# How to disable American spellchecking in vim, and switch purely to British?

Tags: spell-checking, spelling

I tried `:set spell spelllang=en_gb` in my vim, but I noticed that *summarization* is not highlighted as incorrect.  Shouldn't it be wrong?  How to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!